# why http results is not printing in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

It would be a small issue

```
$.getJSON("some url", function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

above call is giving response in network:-

```
    {results : [
{ "Year":"2012 "

}
```

But I am not able to print it in the console window

Comment: Where do you try to `console.log` it? In your code, as far as I see, the `console.log` works

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the response and not an error instead?

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: Do you have any filters in your console?  what browser are you using?

Comment: The call looks right to me especially if the URL is correct. Run the code and check network request and response.

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: Do you get an error? Does it print `undefined` or an empty string? Or does it fail silently?

Comment: according to johnny 5, how about try ```.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {console.log(error);})``` to see if it fails?

Comment: Make sure your are looking at XHR requests in your network panel

Answer (score 0):

Under console, under "Custom Levels"  make sure that "verbose" is selected to make sure the console.log is not being filtered out. 9/10 times if you are not getting a message (and there are no JS errors) it is because the filter is hiding it.

Comment: Ok, try this to log the raw object as a string:



$.getJSON("some url", function(data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); });

Comment: I tried this too. previously same url was giving some XMLhttp error then I added callback? after the url . its not giving the error and giving a response in a network but also not showing anything in console.

Comment: What does your data object look like? Can you post an example of what the returned JSON looks like?

Comment: Thats the response which I am getting if I go check network      {results : [
{ "Year":"2012 "

}..

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(data.response.data)` for getting the exact json response from backend.